# mongo-connector failed to start with following error:

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

The setup was running fine two days ago. Since then i had shutdown mongo connector and mongo-db was running in the background. But i hadn't run any query on mongo.

Now i tried starting mongo-connector this morning and it failed to start.

```
viki@viki-pc:~/Documents/elasticSearch$ mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t localhost:9200 -d /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/elastic_doc_manager.py
2014-12-08 11:43:49,870 - INFO - Beginning Mongo Connector
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 284, in run
self.read_oplog_progress()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 271, in read_oplog_progress
if not isinstance(data[0], list):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am trying to connect mongo with elastic search. And it was working fine 2 days ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

solved it by assigning a different oplog status file while starting mongo-connector

```
mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t localhost:9200 -d /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/elastic_doc_manager.py --oplog-ts oplogstatus.txt
```

Update:
you can also delete the existing oplogstatus file and restart mongo-connector that will also work. But if the ES index gets corrupted then this wont fix the problem.
In such cases i delete the index and remove the oplogstatus file and then re-create the index from scratch.

Comment: It solved my problem but can you please expain why we need to assign diffrent oplog status file

Comment: I have observed this happens when say we posted a wrong structure or document to ES and one of that document causes an issue. I think (i am not sure), that this causes the latest index id on ES to get corrupted. Next time we try to re-run mongo connector and it tries to update that index it fails. Which continues to happening. I have not tried other solutions like pulling the oplog count back by one or increasing the count by 1. i will try these the next time i face this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vikash such nice explanation.